# Struggling with x axis scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

My dateset                                                                                       date nuc small large acc                                                               2019-10-25 10:00:21 213820 346040 1520230 151959         2019-10-25  10:07:06 278956 378901 1567972 167820        2019-10-25 10:14:11 298765 398765  157896 176890          I have a dataset like 2019-10-25 10:00:21. While am plotting the graphs with date and other variable I got the graph but I want to rescale my x axis.
I want to display my entire time and date both should be in my x axis but it's showing 3 hours gap time in my x axis.i tired lots of things but it´s not coming the code which I entered was:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data,aes(x=date)) +
geom_line(aes(y=data1)) +
scale_x_datetime(labels=date_formet("%m/%d%/Y %H:%M"),breaks=date_breaks("1hour"))
```

but it's shows:

> Error in cut.POSIXt(date,time,right=TRUE,include.lowest=TURE): invalid specification of 'breaks'.

I tired alot but I can't find the answer I hope surely I will get some ideas about this here [image]

Comment: tried: `scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%m/%d%/Y %H:%M"),breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"))`?

Comment: Please include sample dataframe you are using to generate the plot. See [mre] for guidance setting out information to allow others to help you more effectively.